# Sequelize many to many documentation

Tags: node.js, many-to-many, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a many to many association between projects and tasks using node and sequelize. I cannot figure out how to create new 'Tasks' with variable names that can be accumulated as an array for the project.setTasks function as the documentation here gives as an example with ALOT of detail missing. http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#associations-many-to-many

here is the example they give:

```
Project.hasMany(Task)
Task.hasMany(Project)

Project.create()...
Task.create()...
Task.create()...

// save them... and then:
project.setTasks([task1, task2]).success(function() {
// saved!
```

})

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "variable names" exactly.

However, [here's](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/test/associations/has-many.test.js#L712) an example from the sequelize test suite, as copied below with my comments:

```
    // Define the models
    this.User = this.sequelize.define('User', { username: DataTypes.STRING });
    this.Task = this.sequelize.define('Task', { title: DataTypes.STRING, active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN });

    // Setup associations
    this.User.hasMany(this.Task);
    this.Task.hasMany(this.User);

    // using promises, sync the database, then create a user and two tasks
    return this.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(function() {
      return Promise.all([
        self.User.create({ username: 'John'}),
        self.Task.create({ title: 'Get rich', active: true}),
        self.Task.create({ title: 'Die trying', active: false})
      ]);
    }).spread(function (john, task1, task2) {
      // This line below is only relevant to the tests.
      self.tasks = [task1, task2];

      // Using the created (and saved) tasks and user, set the tasks and return the promise
      return john.setTasks([task1, task2]);
    });
```

**Edit** I agree that the sequelize documentation is still too light, but I've found it a good framework so far to use.  I recommend when in doubt either reading the unit tests, or writing your own tests to confirm behaviours.

**Edit** Note you can also use `.addTask` and `.removeTask` instead of simply setting them all. See [the docs](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/1.7.8/associations#associating-objects)

Comment: Can you do both the insert and setting references in one statement?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You'd need to use promises as shown in order to wait for the created tasks to exist in the database before setting them on the user.

Comment: Looks like you can do it in `setTasks([task1, task2],{save:false})`